# Using Induction to prove a squared summation statement

Tags: summation, induction

I have the following problem:

Let $p_{1}, . . . , p_n$ be positive real numbers such that $\sum_{k=1}^{n} p_k = 1$.

Prove:

$\sum_{k=1}^{n} p_k^2 \geq \frac{1}{n}$ and

$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{p_k} \geq n^2$.

I am not sure how to approach this problem.

Trying to prove the first statement: I tried squaring the summation term $\sum_{k=1}^{n} p_k$ and got $\sum_{k=1}^{n} p_k^2 + \sum_{k\neq j}^{n} p_k p_j$

So $\sum_{k=1}^{n} p_k^2 = 1-\sum_{k\neq j}^{n} p_k p_j$

Subbing into the statement I'm trying to prove: $1-\sum_{k\neq j}^{n} p_k p_j \geq \frac{1}{n}$

I can't prove this as I don't know how many terms are in $\sum_{k\neq j}^{n} p_k p_j$, and am not sure how to figure it out.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I suspect you've recently learned the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Applying that to the right things yields short proofs.

Answer (score 1):

The Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality: Let $A=(\sum_{k=1}^np_k^2)(\sum_{k=1}^nq_k^2).$ Let $B= (\sum_{k=1}^n p_kq_k)^2.$ Let $C=\sum \sum_{1\le j<k\le n}(p_jq_k-p_kq_j)^2.$

Then $A\ge B$ because $A-B=C\ge 0.$

In your Q let every $q_k=1.$

Geometrically, in $\Bbb R^n,$ if $O$ is the origin and $(p_1,...,p_n)=P\ne O\ne Q=(q_1,...,q_n)$ then $A=|OP|^2\cdot |OQ|^2$ and $B=|OP|^2\cdot |OQ|^2\cos^2 POQ$  and $C=|OP|^2\cdot|OQ|^2\sin^2 POQ.$